# how to transfer values from the controller in a template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

page displays a list of users and sorting form:

```
....
...
<%= form_tag(admin_users_path, method: 'get') do %>
  <%= select_tag "fld_order", options_for_select([ "Ascending", "Descending" ], quantity) %>
  <%= select_tag "fld_quantity", options_for_select([ "5", "10", "50", "100" ], order) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Sort", class: "btn_submit" %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
      def index
        quantity = params[:fld_quantity] || 10
        order = params[:fld_order] || 'Ascending'

        if params[:fld_order] == 'Descending'
          @users = ::User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => quantity).order(name: :DESC)
        else
          @users = ::User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => quantity).order(name: :ASC)
        end

render :index, :locals => {:quantity => quantity, :order => order}
      end
```

Sorting works. but I need to match the values in the form of the actual. The problem is that they always default.

please help transfer `quantity, order` from the controller to the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order` and `quantity` variables needs to be instance variables, and remove the `render` - it's not needed:

```
  def index
    @quantity = params[:fld_quantity] || 10
    @order = params[:fld_order] || 'Ascending'

    if params[:fld_order] == 'Descending'
      @users = ::User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => quantity).order(name: :DESC)
    else
      @users = ::User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => quantity).order(name: :ASC)
    end
  end
```

I also think `get` is the default

```
<%= form_tag(admin_users_path) do %>
  <%= select_tag "fld_order", options_for_select([ "Ascending", "Descending" ], @quantity) %>
  <%= select_tag "fld_quantity", options_for_select([ "5", "10", "50", "100" ], @order) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Sort", class: "btn_submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Also check for spelling mistakes or typos in your code :-)